# Expected a ")" or ";" errors when splitting up scripts that worked as one script

Tags: c++

I previously had one script that included a function and the main in one script.  I decided to have main on its own but now running into an error that isn't clear to me.  The scripts are below.  I can add the rest if necessary.  But yeah, if I don't have `bfs.h` and `main.cpp` and have main where BFs is defined then there are no issues.  Getting errors in `bfs.h` and `main.cpp` though.  Comments at the lines...

bfs.h

```
#ifndef BFS
#define BFS

#include "graph.h"

int* BFS(Graph G, int V, int r);  // error here at G, int and )

#endif
```

Exact error messages

1)  At G - this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

2)  At Int - expected an indentifer

3)  At r  -expected a ';'

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bfs.h"
#include "graph.h"

int main() {
    int V = 4;
    Graph G(V);  // ERROR HERE - expected a ";"
    G.addEdge(0, 1);
    G.addEdge(0, 2);
    G.addEdge(1, 2);
    G.addEdge(2, 0);
    G.addEdge(2, 3);
    int* parents = BFS(G, V, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        std::cout << parents[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Exact error - "expected a ;"

graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH
#define GRAPH

#include <list>

class Graph {
    int V;
    std::list<int> *adj;

public:
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    std::list<int> getAdj(int u);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have both:

```
#define BFS
```

and

```
int* BFS(Graph G, int V, int r);
```

as this will change the function name, during pre-processing. As a first step, please try

```
#ifndef BFS_H
#define BFS_H
```

instead. Does that fix the error?

Comment: Yep, that did it!  Didn't think to check that since the errors pointed at other things.